# Product slider for VPS page

Tags: jquery

I have a product slider, and it needs to have 2 sets of plans. 1 for linux and 1 for windows. Now when a users clicks the Windows button it will change the plans - although this doesn't take effect until they slide it, another problem I need to figure out but thats minor compared to this one - and it does. But now I need to figure out how to change the links as well.

Heres my code to my `solution` that I think should work...

```
function toSubmit() {
    var form = $('#signup_form');
    var osValue = form.find('input[name=configoption5]:checked').val();
    var locationValue = form.find('#select-locationoption:selected').val();
    var osradio = $('input[name="configoption5"]');

    if (s.getValue() == '0') {
        if ('osradio'.val() == "55") {
            window.location.href = 'https://clients.HIDE.com/cart.php?
            a = add & pid = 47 & configoption[5] = ' + osValue + ' && configoption[6] = ' +     
            locationValue;
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'https://clients.HIDENEWLINK.com/cart.php?
            a = add & pid = 47 & configoption[5] = ' + osValue + ' && configoption[6] = ' + 
            locationValue;
        }

    } else if (s.getValue() == '1') {
        window.location.href = 'https://clients.HIDE.com/cart.php?    
        a = add & pid = 47 & configoption[5] = ' + osValue + ' && configoption[6] = ' + 
        locationValue;
    } else if (s.getValue() == '2') {
        window.location.href = 'https://clients.HIDE.com/cart.php?
        a = add & pid = 47 & configoption[5] = ' + osValue + ' && configoption[6] = ' +     
        locationValue;
    } else if (s.getValue() == '3') {
        window.location.href = 'https://clients.HIDE.com/cart.php?
        a = add & pid = 47 & configoption[5] = ' + osValue + ' && configoption[6] = ' + 
        locationValue;
    }
}

/* and so on */
```

The first if statement is different from the rest, thats my attempt at setting it so the order link changes when windows is selected (via radio, so `val=55`).

You can see it live [here](http://varcoedesign.com/preview/shocksrv/vps.php). Theres probably a way better way to writing javascript code that is beyond my knowledge. If you click the windows icon and drag the slider over once it will change the plans - which it's supposed to do. Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the order links.

Heres the full code: http://pastebin.com/Byu9rzRw

PLEASE help. I've struggled with this for many hours, I imagine a jQuery expert could solve this in 2 minutes so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all inline, so it's a bit difficult to understand well and to edit. Anyway I've achieved the goal to let the slider to be updated from the radios, typing in consolle this line of jQuery

```
$('input[name=configoption5]').change(function(){$(s).trigger('change')})
```

I think you should try something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var packages = [
                    ['1024', '1', '25', '1', '$10.00'],
                    ['2048', '2', '50', '2', '$20.00'],
                    ['3072', '3', '75', '4', '$35.00'],
                    ['4096', '4', '100', '6', '$50.00'],
                    ['6144', '6', '125', '8', '$65.00'],
                    ['8192', '8', '200', '10', '$95.00'],
                    ['10240', '10', '300', '15', '$125.00'],
                    ['12288', '12', '500', '20', '$150.00'],
                    ['16384', '12', '750', '25', '$200.00']
    ];



        $("input[name='configoption5']").change(function () {

            // Windows Plans
            if ($(this).val() == "55") {
                packages = [
                    ['10241', '1', '25', '1', '$10.00'],
                    ['20481', '2', '50', '2', '$20.00'],
                    ['30721', '3', '75', '4', '$35.00'],
                    ['40961', '4', '100', '6', '$50.00'],
                    ['61441', '6', '125', '8', '$65.00'],
                    ['81921', '8', '200', '10', '$95.00'],
                    ['102401', '10', '300', '15', '$125.00'],
                    ['122881', '12', '500', '20', '$150.00'],
                    ['163841', '12', '750', '25', '$200.00']];
            } else {
                packages = [
                    ['1024', '1', '25', '1', '$10.00'],
                    ['2048', '2', '50', '2', '$20.00'],
                    ['3072', '3', '75', '4', '$35.00'],
                    ['4096', '4', '100', '6', '$50.00'],
                    ['6144', '6', '125', '8', '$65.00'],
                    ['8192', '8', '200', '10', '$95.00'],
                    ['10240', '10', '300', '15', '$125.00'],
                    ['12288', '12', '500', '20', '$150.00'],
                    ['16384', '12', '750', '25', '$200.00']];
            }

            // ToDo:Here you should check someway if the 's' object was
            // already created
            $(s).trigger('change');

        });

    function _(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
</script>
```